# Grab response message from .NET Core API with ky

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api, http-status-codes, ky

I use [ky package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ky) for sending HTTP requests to web api. Everything works except handling error messages.

Let me show you my source code:

```cs
// api method
[HttpPost("Test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody] TestViewModel model)
{
    if(model.Test)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCode.Status200OK, "Success message");
    }
    else
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Error message");
    }
}
```

My aim is get and display *Success message* or *Error message* text on the frontend.

Client side:

```js
//webclient.js
import ky from "ky";

export const webclient = ky.create({
  prefixUrl: "http://localhost:62655/api",
});
```

Firing API call:

```js
//testAPI.js
import { webclient } from '../../common/webclient';

const result = await webclient.post('Order/Test', { json: { ...model } }).json();
console.log(result);
```

If the status code is equal to 200 the message (*Success message*) show in console properly, but for 500 (or 400, or any else) console remains empty.

DevTools confirm that API returns 500 status code with message *Error message* so it's not an API problem.

The question is: how can I obtain an error message with `ky`?

Comment: This _"ky"_ library doesn't seem very mature. I would highly recommend Axios instead

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ky#api) states _"Unlike the Body methods of `window.Fetch`; these will throw an `HTTPError` if the response status is not in the range of `200...299`"_. According to that, it should be throwing an error so have you tried wrapping the code with [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)?

Comment: @Phil catched exception doesn't contains message too: `{"name":"HTTPError","response":{},"request":{},"options":{"credentials":"same-origin","prefixUrl":"http://localhost:62655/api/","hooks":{"beforeRequest":[null],"beforeRetry":[],"afterResponse":[]},"json":{"test":false},"method":"POST","headers":{},"retry":{"limit":2,"methods":["get","put","head","delete","options","trace"],"statusCodes":[408,413,429,500,502,503,504],"afterStatusCodes":[413,429,503],"maxRetryAfter":null},"throwHttpErrors":true,"timeout":10000,"signal":{},"body":"{\"test\":false}"}}`

Comment: That's nice. And?

Comment: And the catched exception still not contain my status code message: *Error message*. So wrapping the code in try...catch not helped.

Comment: See https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky/issues/107#issuecomment-476048453. Personally, this `ky` library seems like a waste of time

Comment: Solution from provided url works. You can post it as answer and I will accept it. BTW. You're right about this package, probably I'm gonna switch it to another.

Answer (score 0):

The `ky` library doesn't seem very mature but I did find this issue thread which might help ~ https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky/issues/107#issuecomment-476048453

I would strongly suggest you just stick to vanilla `fetch` where you're in full control of handling the [response text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) if required

```js
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:62655/api/Order/Test", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({ ...model })
})

if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${await response.text()}`)
} 
console.log(await response.json())
```